Modified version of 2 Eggs Problem
Original problem:
You are tasked with determining the threshold floor of a 100-story building from which an egg will break if dropped. The problem is as follows:

You are given 2 eggs.
An egg breaks only if dropped from a floor higher than or equal to the threshold floor.
If an egg breaks, it cannot be used again.
If an egg does not break, it can be reused.

The goal is to find the threshold floor using the minimum number of attempts in the worst-case scenario.
This is a very famous problem and the strategy for this is explained on this website http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/july22012/index.html .
I had two follow up questions

What is the expected value of number of egg drops if the above strategy is followed assuming uniform probability distribution for the threshold floor?

What is the optimal strategy to minimize Expected number of egg drops?


Feel free to take a more realistic probability distribution for the above parts.
t = int(input())  # Number of test cases

for _ in range(t):
    n = int(input())

    # Initialize worst-case DP array
    dp_worstcase = [float('inf')] * (n + 1)
    dp_worstcase[0] = 0
    dp_worstcase[1] = 0
    dp_worstcase[2] = 1

    # Initialize floor array
    floor = [0] * (n + 1)
    floor[2] = 1

    # Compute worst-case DP values and track floor positions
    for i in range(3, n + 1):
        for j in range(i-1,0,-1):
            new_value = 1 + max(dp_worstcase[i - j], j - 1)
            if new_value < dp_worstcase[i]:
                dp_worstcase[i] = new_value
                floor[i] = j

    print(dp_worstcase[n])

    # Initialize expected-case DP array
    dp_expected = [float('inf')] * (n + 1)
    dp_expected[0] = 0
    dp_expected[1] = 0
    dp_expected[2] = 1

    # Compute expected-case DP values
    for i in range(3, n + 1):
        f = floor[i]
        dp_expected[i] = 1 + (f / n) * (f)/2 + (1 - f / n) * dp_expected[i-f]
        #Justification for dp_expected 
        #There is probability f/n that the egg cracks at floor f and after that expected value is f/2
        #There is a probability (1-f/n) that egg doesn't crack on floor f and then the expected value is dp_expected[i-f]
    print(dp_expected[n])


Python code for Part 1 (I want a closed form).

What is the value you get for Part 1?

Ok, I got something like 11.56 which seems wrong.

@ArnabGoyal I didn't get the part of code where you compute dp_expected. Can you expand (in the question) the math of that part, why is it so? After that, having any closed form on f, it might be possible to construct dp_expected in something like matrix form with matrix powers, then doing singular value decomposition on the matrix we have to raise in a power, we might develop closer to the closed form. Thanks.

@garondal I got the answer as 4.99 there might be a little error in my logic as I am assuming that when an egg cracks on floor f still there is uniform distribution for threshold floor

@AlexeyBurdin I have added comments in my code if the logic is still not clear let me know.Also there was a slight error in the previous code.

Since I am taking uniform distribution it guarantees that egg will crack on $n$ th floor I think I should modify the initial strategy a bit like for $n$ $= 2$ answer should be 1 instead of 2

@garondal with modifications I am getting the expected value as $10.714646795233877$

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
With the strategy given for two eggs at the linked site, the number of drops $\ d_t\ $ taken to determine the threshold is uniquely determined by its location $\ t\ .$  The expected number of drops needed is therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(d_T\big)&\ed\sum_{t=0}^{100}d_t\mathbb{P}(T=t)\\
&=\frac{1}{101}\sum_{t=0}^{100}d_t\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
for a uniformly distributed random threshold $\ T\ .^\color{red}{\dagger}$ For convenience I'll define a sequence of quantities $\ \big\{f_i\big\}_{i=0}^{12}\ $ by $\ f_0\ed0\ $ and
\begin{align}
f_i&\ed\cases{\text{floor from which }\ i^\text{th}\ \text{ drop is made if none of}\\
\text{the first }\ i-1 \text{ drops breaks the first egg.}}\\
&=\cases{\frac{i(29-i)}{2}&if $\ i\le11$\\
100&if $\ i=12$}\ .
\end{align}
The quantities $\ d_t\ $ are then given by
\begin{align}
d_t=\cases{i+2&if $\ t=f_i, 0\le i\le10$\\
12&if $\ t\in\big\{f_{11},f_{12}\big\}=\{99,100\}$\\
i+t+1-f_{i-1}&if$\ f_{i-1}<t<f_i-1,1\le i\le11$\\
i+f_i-1-f_{i-1}&if $\ t=f_i-1, i\le11$}\ .
\end{align}
Therefore the identity \eqref{1} becomes
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(d_T\big)&=\frac{d_{100}}{101}+\frac{d_{99}}{101}+\frac{1}{101}\sum_{t=0}^{98}d_t\\
&=\frac{24}{101}+\frac{1}{101}\sum_{i=0}^{10}\sum_{t=f_i}^{f_{i+1}-1}d_t\\
&=\frac{24}{101}+\frac{1}{101}\sum_{i=0}^{10}\left(i+2+i+f_{i+1}-f_i+\sum_{t=f_i+1}^{f_{i+1}-2}d_t\right)\\
&=\frac{24}{101}+\frac{1}{101}\sum_{i=0}^{10}\left(\vphantom{\sum_{t=f_i+1}^{f_{i+1}-2}}i+16\right.\\
&\left.\hspace{9em}+\sum_{t=f_i+1}^{f_{i+1}-2}\left(i+t+2-\frac{i(29-i)}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{255}{101}+\sum_{i=0}^{10}\frac{\big(f_{i+1}-2-f_i\big)\big(f_i+f_{i+1}+3+i(i-27)\big)}{202}\\
&=\frac{255}{101}+\sum_{i=0}^{10}\frac{(12-i)\big(i+17\big)}{202}\\
&=\frac{1047}{101}=10.\overline{3633}\ .
\end{align}
Since this differs a little from the value you've given in the comments, I've included a table of the values of $\ d_t\ $ for $\ 0\le t\le99\ $ in the table below, the entry in row $\ i\ $ and column $\ j\ $ (with $\ 0\le i,j\le9\ $) is $\ d_{10i+j}\ .$  Checking the values in the table is fairly easy.  For $\ t=65\ ,$ for instance, you'll  drop the first egg from floors $14,27,39,50$ and $60$ without its breaking. You'll then drop it from floor $69$, when it breaks. Next, you'll drop the second egg from floors $61,62,63,64$ and $65$ without its breaking. You'll then drop it from floor $66$, when it will break, thus telling you that $\ t=65\ .$ The total number of egg drops you've made to determine this is $12$, as indicated in row $6$ and column $5$ of the table. That said, I haven't checked every single entry in the table by hand, so if you find any errors, please let me know. It also shouldn't be difficult (if somewhat tedious) to check that the entries in the table sum to $1035$.  To get the value of $\ \sum_\limits{i=0}^{100}d_t\ $ you then have to add $\ d_{100}=12\ $ to this, which gives you $1047$.
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
0 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
\hline
1 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline
2 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
3 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 5 \\
\hline
4 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 14 \\
\hline
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 14 \\
\hline
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & \color{red}{12} & 13 & 14 & 14 & 8 \\
\hline
7 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
\hline
8 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 14 \\
\hline
9 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 14 & 12 \\
\hline
\end{array}
I've also written a Magma script to try and answer  your second question. Unfortunately the answer it gives is obviously wrong, and it has so far resisted all my efforts to track down the remaining errors.  If I ever manage to get it working, I'll add the results to my answer.
$^\color{red}{\dagger}$ I'm taking the value of the threshold to be the highest floor from which an egg dropped won't break, or zero, if an egg dropped from the first floor will break.

If the probability is $\frac{1}{101}$ for each floor, then you just can sum over all possible numbers of egg throws and divide this in the end by 101.

Threshold is no floor: 2 drops (14 and 1) (egg always breaks)
Threshold is 1st floor: 3 drops (14 and 1, 2)
Threshold is 2nd floor: 4 drops (14 and 1, 2, 3)
Threshold is 3rd floor: 5 drops (14 and 1, 2, 3, 4)
...
Threshold is 12th floor: 14 drops (14 and 1, 2, 3, 4, ... ,13)
Threshold is 13th floor: 14 drops (14 and 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 13)

This is $2+3+\ldots 13 +14+14=\frac{(2+ 14)\cdot 13}{2}+14$

Threshold is the 14th floor: 3 drops (14, 27, 15)
...
Threshold is the 25th floor: 14 drops (14, 27, 15, ..., 26)
Threshold is the 26th floor: 14 drops (14, 27, 15, ..., 26)

This is $3+4+\ldots+14+14=\frac{(3+ 14)\cdot 12}{2}+14$
Then we get $4+5+\ldots+14+14$ and so on. In total you get up to 99
$$\sum_{i=1}^{11} \dfrac{(1+i+14)(14-i)}{2}+14=1023$$
and $+12+12$ for the 99th and last floor, so an expected value of $10.\overline{3663}$.
Edit: I forgot the 99th floor.
